# How can I read()/write() against a python HTTPConnection?

Tags: python, http, rpc

I've got python code of the form:

```
(o,i) = os.popen2 ("/usr/bin/ssh host executable")  
ios = IOSource(i,o)
```

Library code then uses this IOSource, doing writes() and read()s against inputstream i and outputstream o.

Yes, there is IPC going on here..  Think RPC.

I want to do this, but in an HTTP fashion rather than spawning an ssh.

I've done python http before with:

```
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost',8000)  
conn.connect()  
conn.request('POST','/someurl/')  
response=conn.getresponse()
```

How do I get the inputstream/outputstream from the HTTPConnection so that my lib code can read from/write to just like the ssh example above?

Comment: don't use os.popen2(). subprocess module is the recommended way to run subprocesses on python.

Comment: don't use either to communicate with ssh. Use pexpect/twisted.conch/paramiko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for output:

```
output = response.read()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httpresponse-objects

for input:
pass your data in the POST body of your request